# Windows 7 installer asks for CD DVD drivers, but need SATA driver and doesn't accept them

Tags: windows, drivers, installation, sata

During the installation of Windows 7 via USB-Stick on a new PC, windows asks for driver:

German text from windows. I have only german  as installation language.

```
Ein erforderlicher CD-/DVD-Laufwerkgerätetreiber fehlt. Wenn Sie über eine     Treiberdiskette, -CD, .DVD, bzw. ein USB-Flashlaufwerk verfügen, legen Sie diese(s) jetzt ein.

Hinweis: Wenn sich im CD-/DVD-Laufwerk ein Windows-Installationsdatenträger befindet, können Sie ihn bei diesen Schritt problemlos entfernen
```

Translation by me:

```
A needed CD-/DVD driver is missing. If you have a driver disk, plug it in now.
```

After searching in the net, this message is very confusing. The Actual problem is access to the SATA-Interfaces. In my special case, no CD or DVD drive is available. So I took all the drivers from ASRock onto an HDD and connected it to the board. The Windows installation routine finds an appropriate driver (Floopy(v14.6.0.1029_PV)) und I can select it. After a few seconds this failure messare pops up.

```
Der Gerätetreiber [Intel(R) 100 Series/C230 Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller (E:\ASRock Treiber\dl\Floppy(v14.6.0.1029_PV)\f6flpy-x64\iaAHCIC.inf)] konnte nicht installiert werden. Wenden Sie sich an den Hersteller, um einen aktualisierten Treiber zu erhalten.
```

Translation by me:

```
The driver cannot be installed. Please contact the manufactorer.
```

It's confusing. Windows recognized the HDD with the drivers on it, because I can select them. So why it asks me for drivers?

I'm at the end. So sysadmin come on. What's the point here?

- Mainboard: ASRock Fatal1ty Gaming K4
- SSD: Samsung 850 EVO
- Optical drive: none

To prevent questions:

- Yes, I have googled ;-)
- Win 7 is currectly downloaded, inclusive SP1 and in 64 Bit
- The USB-Stick is plugged in an USB2.0 port
- The UEFI-Version is the latest (P2.20)
- Neither the latest drivers, nor these on the delivered cd are accepted.
- SATA Mode Selection: AHCI
- SATA Device Type: SSD (only at the SSD, not the HDD with the drivers on it)

Comment: Are you selecting the right bit version of the driver? It must match the OS, 32 or 64bit.

Comment: Yes Sir, it's the 64bit version. The 32bit version is not even detected by the Installer.

Comment: Try making the usb W7 stick again from scratch. If it is made using an iso of W7, make a new iso.

Comment: So i should unpack the contents of the iso, create a new bootable stick and put the contents then onto the stick again as an iso? The iso is downloaded today.

Comment: Does not matter when you downloaded it, it may be corrupt, I would get a fresh copy, there are utilities that convert the iso to usb, or you can do as you suggest, unpack and do a simple copy to the usb if it has already been prepped to be bootable.

Comment: Done. Exact the same behavior. I used a windows installation cd, that has worked on different system in the past. The installer asks for driver, I can select them, and then it says the drivers couldn't be installed.